# WinDbg: Unable to verify checksum for EXE file

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, windbg

I realize a question with the exact title has already been answered, but the steps there requires running the compiler and linker manually, whereas I want to use cmake.

I am trying to debug a C program with WinDbg.  But I'm getting this error:

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for main.exe
```

Reading a mailing list thread<sup>[1](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.windbg/c/ZpF3zk9iXhA)</sup>, I'm guessing I need to add a few flags, namely '/Zi' and '/Release'.  But I'm building my project with cmake, and I don't know how to add those flags properly so that I can build my program using GNU toolchain with debug symbols too.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.00)
project(Hello LANGUAGES C)

add_executable(main src/main.c)
```

With the above cmake file, my program is built properly.  Even a pdb file is generated, which is read by WinDbg no problem.  But I can't see the line information with `.lines` and no source file is shown when debugging the EXE; only assembly commands are shown.

After the reading the mail thread (mentioned above), I checked the checksum value of my EXE.  It's zero.  Now I need to know how to set up a cmake file so it produces EXE with debug symbols with proper checksum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checksum-verification warning turned out not to be the issue (it was just a warning after all, not an error).  WinDbg didn't load line information.  Either it's the default (although I don't know why that would be) or I mistakenly turned it off myself.  Whatever the case, here is how you turn it on:

```
.lines -e
```

After that, WinDbg was able to bring up the source window by its own accord when I started debugging.